# How to store awk / sed output into a variable (from a log)?

Tags: awk, sed

I am trying to extract the JSON data from the following log stream (coming from `adb`):

```
09-29 13:53:16.619 20268 20268 D Activity: onSuccess(): {"Data": {"Samples": [-247, -255, -260, -256, -246, -234, -220, -210, -208, -209, -210, -210, -204, -196, -185, -172], "Timestamp": 3543392}, "Uri": "214730------/Meas/---/500", "Method": "PUT"}
```

I can extract the JSON data by following commands (both work fine and print the output into the console):

```
adb logcat | sed -n 's/.*onSuccess(): //p'

adb logcat | awk -F'onSuccess\(\)\: ' '{ print $2 }'
adb logcat | awk -F'onSuccess\(\)\: ' '{ X=$2; print X }'
```

Now I am trying to put the output of sed/awk into a variable as follows:

```
# I am not getting anything for following command
adb logcat | X=$(sed -n 's/.*onSuccess(): //p') | echo $X

# But, following command is printing `X --- ` (contineously)
adb logcat | awk -F'onSuccess\(\)\: ' '{ X=$2; print X| cmd="echo X --- $X"; close(cmd); }'
```

However, I am not getting anything from `X=$(sed -n 's/.*onSuccess(): //p')` part and it gets stuck. But the `awk -F'onSuccess\(\)\: ' '{ X=$2; print X| cmd="echo X --- $X"; close(cmd); }'` is printing `X ---`  contineously (it seems $X is not available at `echo X --- $X`).

How can I get a substituted result (i.e., `$X`) at the next pipe command (i.e., `echo X --- $X`)?

Thanks!

Comment: `X=$(sed -n 's/.*onSuccess(): //p')` will run in a subshell and so will `echo $X`, in another. They won't be able to access each other's values.

Comment: Can't `X=$(adb logcat | ...)` work?

Comment: Thanks @konsolebox! The command - `X=$(adb logcat | awk -F'onSuccess\(\)\: ' '{ print $2 }') | echo $X` helps a little (and stop printing the value of X maybe it can hold up to certain length). I guess this is not real-time text processing.

Comment: Running shell commands in a pipeline runs them in a subshell. Please look up what a subshell is. Your added `| echo $X` command doesn't make sense.

Comment: you probably want `X=$(...) ; echo "$x"`. Note the semi-colon NOT the `|` char (-; . Good luck.

Comment: @shelter: when testuser uses `X=$(...)`, you need `echo "$X"`. Better is `x=$(...) ; echo "$x"` (use semi-colon AND double quotes around `$x`).

Comment: @WalterA : Yep! Typo. Sorry!